# Run only selected mocha tests in IntelliJ IDEA family IDEA

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, mocha.js

If we'll click the button from at left of `describe` expression:

[image]

the command like below will be generated:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\...\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha.js"  
  --ui bdd 
  --reporter "C:\Users\Takeshi Tokugawa\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9011.34\plugins\nodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js" 
  "D:\IntelliJ IDEA\..\Tests\Automated\Logic\Classes\Empty\EmptyClass.test.ts" 
  --grep "^Empty class "
```

We can see `--grep "^Empty class "` there, however it just excludes the displaying of results of all tests except `"^Empty class "`, however all tests will be run. It is the huge hindrance during the debugging.

For example, I have 2 tests: **EmptyClass.test.ts** and **Importing.test.ts**. I'll add the `console.log("FOO");` and `console.log("BAR");` to these tests respectively:

[image]

Now, I'll run above console command. Both `console.log("FOO");` from **EmptyClass.test.ts** and ``console.log("BAR");` from **Importing.test.ts** has been executed. And also, all code inside tests has been executed. This is not what need. I can't stand it is the huge hindrance during the debugging.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean saying that all tests will be run? Note that all describe calls are executed prior to running tests to set up hooks and queue test despite the `--grep`, etc. options, see https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4086#issuecomment-549329031

Comment: @lena I am sorry about unclear problem formulation. I have added the explanations to the question.  "Note that all ..." - does it mean "What you are want it unreachable neither  by the IntelliJ IDEA nor by the Mocha. Consider the other testing framework"?

Comment: Yes, it's a Mocha limitation, you will face the same issue if your run mocha with `--grep` in terminal. Nothing can be done on IDEA end to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will face the same issue if your run mocha with `--grep` in terminal. All describe calls are executed prior to running tests to set up hooks and queue test despite the `--grep`, etc. options, see https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4086#issuecomment-549329031

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If it is the Mocha limitation, no claims to IntelliJ IDEA.